# Is there a free video camera software to switch between multiple cameras?

Tags: windows, camera, live-video

My church wants to get 2 or so cameras and a projector and would like to do live feeds of whats going on on a big screen. I need to pull live streams onto a computer and then change what shows on the projector from one to another.

Comment: and which operating system would this be for?

Comment: Windows Xp, Vista, or Windows 7 the computer for this has not been built yet but they do not want a Mac

Comment: CamUniversal 3.8 is a WebCam Tool

Comment: Is there a reason for the pc to be there?  Otherwise a simple video switch may be much cheaper/easier

Comment: EasyCCTV (Shareware, try before you buy) http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/WebCam/EasyCCTV.shtml

Comment: They also want to run powerpoints and videos from church functions

Comment: @Brian, per Keck's suggestion, could you use a VGA -> RCA (or whatever you use) adapter then hook all the inputs to the switchbox?  `Camera1 - Camera2 - ComputerVideo - Extra`

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently trying MPEG<sub>4</sub>NVR. So far I like it. Free, and ad-free. Find it here http://download.cnet.com/MPEG4-NVR/3000-2348_4-10599755.html

Answer (score 1):

EasyCCTV captures images up to 30 frames per second from any USB video device. The program performs simultaneous recording. You can use your camera(s) as part of a surveillance system.